# Path of the extensions

Tags: visual-studio-code

I noticed that vscode's extensions are stored in the user profile folder.
Is it possible to change the path and put the extensions in the same folder of the program?

Thank you.

Cheers,
BlackSun

Answer (score 0):

Use the `--extensions-dir` command line option for this:

```
$ code --extensions-dir /path/to/install/dir
```